# Azure VM GPU Accelerated image

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, gpu

I am trying to test pixel streaming with the unreal engine. I want to host my VM in azure. I am trying to find an image that includes GPU so that I can support direct x. I can't seem to find an image that includes any video drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The GPU for the Azure VM does not depend on the VM image. It depends on the VM size. See the [VM size for the GPU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-gpu).

Answer (score -1):

I needed an N series VM - and I had to look in a region not close to me to find them. Thanks.